# Store variable anywhere (swap space, disk) but not in physical memory

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management

I know that it's possible to force a variable to be stored in physical memory using mlock() function.

```
void *buffer = malloc(buf_size);
mlock(buffer, buf_size);
// If there is no error when executing these instructions,
// On First Write to buffer, the buffer will be stored in physical memory
```

However, what if we want to make sure that the variable will never reside in physical memory. Is it possible to do that ?  If yes, how Linux allows to do this in userspace.

Answer (score 0):

When something is written to disk, the disk controller reads the contents of the file via [DMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_memory_access). DMA is the abbreviation for *direct memory access*, and the term "memory" is key here. It will access memory. This is even OS independent, because that's implemented in hardware.

```
system("wget http://example.com/?x=2+2");
```

This will store the variable `x` with a value of `4` on my webserver, not in the RAM of your PC. Except for extreme examples like this, I cannot think of any solution.